# How to get cursors from each entity in Google Cloud Datastore query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I'm working with Google Cloud Datastore in my NodeJS application. When I make a query I want to get the cursors for every entity in the response, however, queries only return the end cursor by default. For example when I make a query like:

```js
const query = datastore
    .createQuery(['EntityType'])
    .limit(2)
    .start(start);
const response = await datastore.runQuery(query);
```

I get a response that looks something like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            name: "BLAH",
            age: 21
        },
        {
            name: "BLAH",
            age: 26
        }
    ],
    {
        moreResults: "BLAHBLAHBLAH",
        endCursor: "BLAH2"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get the cursor for every entity in the response? For example I want my response to look something like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            name: "BLAH",
            age: 21,
            cursor: "BLAH1"
        },
        {
            name: "BLAH",
            age: 26,
            cursor: "BLAH2"
        }
    ],
    {
        moreResults: "BLAHBLAHBLAH",
        endCursor: "BLAH2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll want to access the batch directly from the response. You can trace the responses from [IRunQueryResponse](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/a613198468b98feee802850ab745a0ae59e9bd2c/protos/protos.d.ts#L2377) to [response.batch.entityResults.cursor](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/a613198468b98feee802850ab745a0ae59e9bd2c/protos/protos.d.ts#L4686)